# Using raster datasets from a gdb in python

Tags: python, floating-point, gis, raster, arcpy

I'm trying to write a script for converting degrees to radians in python.  A common task and it would just be useful to have around.  The problem I'm getting is that the input raster appears to be being read as a string.  See below:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
import math
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
env.workspace = "C:\Users\OJB\Desktop\University\UsingRAS\UsingRas.gdb"


degrad = math.pi / 180
PythonRad = "Aspect_Deg" * degrad

outCos = Cos("PythonRad")
outCos.save("C:\Users\OJB\Desktop\University\UsingRAS\UsingRas.gdb\PyTest")
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/OJB/Desktop/University/UsingRAS/Scripts/DegtoRad", line 11, in <module>
PythonRad = "Aspect_Deg" * degrad
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I'm not sure how to use this raster without using the quote marks.  I'm very new to Python so any help would be appreciated.

All the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a raster object from the arcpy module to instantiate the raster:

```
from arcpy import Raster

...

ras = Raster('path_to_raster') 
PythonRad = ras * degrad
```

Also, don't forget to check your spatial analyst extension back in when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

First: When you want to use the `\` character in your strings, you have to escape it with another `\`. So your path would look like this: `"C:\\Users\\OJB\\Desktop\\University\\UsingRAS\\UsingRas.gdb"`

This line:

```
PythonRad = "Aspect_Deg" * degrad
```

Doesn't make sense, as you are multiplying a string literal with a float value. You have to first retrieve an object that is multipliable with your float.

Comment: @Constantinus Thanks!  Totally forgot about python's paths and the \\.  The "Aspect_Deg" refers to the grid file I want to use.  I thought if the workspace is set, specific filenames had to be in ""